# Are there any ways to avoid downtime when NPM goes down? (in this case related to GC App Engine Deployment)

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, npm, deployment, cloud

Like many people, I was recently hit by the NPM servers breaking with 429 errors. In my case, Google's App Engine depends on an NPM install for server deployment. As a result of NPM going down, this failed and I was left unable to deploy updates even to our dev environment for several hours.

Whilst GC is very robust, given they can provide no guaruntees (and currently no protection) against this sort of situation, it means very little if the whole system can be taken down by a third party.

I've obviously directed a question towards google about this as well, but I was wondering if anybody else using App Engine or similar products has thoughts on how to mitigate this issue? I don't believe I can simply check in the node modules (and I suspect many would recommend against that) but my knowledge of npm and deployment isn't huge.

I can see there's several other questions related to similar issues, but I haven't been able to find any questions/answers that would help me on the Google App Engine front - at least with my limited understanding of NPM package management.

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal behaviour for App Engine on Node, it has to install the dependencies you specify with the `npm install` command as mentioned in the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/runtime#dependencies).

As mentioned there, the only "workaround" that comes to mind, would be to specify a `yarn.lock` so that yarn is used instead of npm.

Hope you find this useful.